# Debugger does not free memory after detaching from a big application on Windows CE 6.0

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, ram

We have a couple of devices running CE 6 from different vendors. When I attach VS2008SP1 debugger to our (rather huge) application, it takes all the RAM on device. When I detach, memory on device is not freed. If I try to reattach, there is not enough RAM and device hangs. Launching under debugger takes even more RAM, sometimes it cannot start at all.

Our app is big (80MB) and loads half of its modules explicitly, but of course I don't reload modules when I attach/detach/attach debugger.

One of the devices is supposedly has firmware with CE6 Update Rollup Package for Dec 2011. Is there some patch for VS2008 for us, or maybe some patch for CE 6 we could ask vendors to install?